# Conditional if is single and part of the custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, conditional-tags

I want to write code only if it is single and part of the custom taxonomy. Here's how my custom taxonomy edit URL looks like:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=us_pf_category&tag_ID=53&post_type=us_p
```

I tried many different ways but not working. Here's one example:

```
if ( is_single() && has_term( ' ', '53' ) )
```

What's wrong going on? For the regular category, it's working with the `in_category` function. I don't know how things work for custom taxonomy type. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you've got a space in the first argument of `has_term()`. If you want to check for any term then you need to pass an empty string, but a space is not an empty string. Then, [as documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/), the second argument needs to be the taxonomy name.

This should work:

```
if ( is_single() && has_term( '', 'us_pf_category' ) )
```